# Home Depot Purchase History Download

Tags: python, web-scraping

I work for a construction company and have started making dashboards for our Key Metrics.  I do this using Python.  One of the most tedious parts of the process is downloading the daily Home Depot transaction list from our account and adding those items to my spreadsheet.  Is there some way to write a python program to log onto my account and download the CSV sheet from my customer page since they don't have an API I can find?  I know that's a tall task, but if anyone has ever done something like that I would love to know what subjects to start researching.

Comment: you can use selenium to automate the browser part, and have it running on a server daily?

Comment: Thanks!!!  I’m not familiar with Selenium.  I will look into it.

Comment: when you add the data to your excel, do you use Pandas or a another data processing tool?

Comment: I am using Pandas to import the data